# Synchronize with repository + Maven update + clean server in one step

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, build-automation

I have to perform the following actions using Eclipse:

1. Synchronize the project with SVN repository.
2. If there are conflicts, update all non-conflicting files and stop; continue otherwise.
3. Update all incoming changes.
4. Do Maven Update on project.
5. Clean my server in Servers view.

Is there any way to do it all (or at least some actions) in one step? Can I script it somehow?

Comment: Setup a CI server? Checkout Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like Mark says, use a continuous integration tool (i use Atlassian Bamboo) but you can check for a free one like continuum, then define a script to do all your stuff.

Sure, you can also use directly a bash script, but i don't think it will be a good choice.